# Custom Bottom Navigation Bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

how to create custom bottomNavigation Bar in flutter that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: please update the question with, what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar)  plugin will help you design such Bottom Navigation Bar.

[image: Convex]

```
Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
    items: [
      TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.map, title: 'Discovery'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.add, title: 'Add'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.message, title: 'Message'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.people, title: 'Profile'),
  ],
  initialActiveIndex: 2,//optional, default as 0
  onTap: (int i) => print('click index=$i'),
 )
);
```

You can also use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_navigation)plugin

[image: this]